# How to stop replay activity in azure durable functions?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I created 1 activity function and calling it from orchestrator function using powershell commandlet Invoke-DurableActivity. But when I executed the orchestrator function I'm seeing that the code running asynchronous and replay activity causing code to re-run. How can I avoid this re-run as we don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The re-run is part of the design of the framework. The good news is, once the activity finishes, The orchestrator will check internally for the state (result of the activity) and will move to the next step of your workflow.